# String many operations on calculator

Tags: javascript

I am stucked with the logic of one exercise from The Odin Project. I am actually working on a simple calculator and it's almost done (except for minor bugs I think) but I need to implement the last functionality and honestly I don't know where to start.

Basically the exercise says:

> "Users should be able to string together several operations and get
> the right answer, with each pair of numbers being evaluated at a time.
> For example, 12 + 7 - 5 * 3 = should yield 42.
>
> Your calculator should not evaluate more than a single pair of numbers
> at a time. Example: you press a number button (12), followed by an
> operator button (+), a second number button (7), and finally a second
> operator button (-). Your calculator should then do the following:
> first, evaluate the first pair of numbers (12 + 7), second, display
> the result of that calculation (19), and finally, use that result (19)
> as the first number in your new calculation, along with the next
> operator (-)."

The thing is, I'm very lost and confused about this last step and when I try to operate like that on my calculator it simply does not work. It's like I have to priorize multiplying and dividing over adding and subtracting, right? Could anyone enlight me?

Here is the code:

```js
const displayPrevResult = document.querySelector('.prev-result');
const displayCurrentResult = document.querySelector('.current-result');
const equal = document.querySelector('.equal');
const decimal = document.querySelector('.decimal');
const clear = document.querySelector('.clear');

const numberBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
const operatorBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.operator');
let current = '';
let previous = '';
let opString = '';


numberBtn.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        getNum(e.target.textContent);
    })
})

operatorBtn.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        getOp(e.target.textContent);
    })
})


clear.addEventListener('click', clearCalc);


// Operate when clicking equal
equal.addEventListener('click', () => {
    current = parseFloat(current);
    previous = parseFloat(previous);

    if (opString === '+') {
        current = add(previous, current);
    } else if (opString === '-') {
        current = subtract(previous, current);
    } else if (opString === 'x') {
        current = multiply(previous, current);
    } else if (opString === '÷') {
        if (current === 0) {
            clearCalc();
            displayCurrentResult.textContent = 'ERROR';
            return;
        }
        current = divide(previous, current);
    }

    displayCurrentResult.textContent = current;
})

function clearCalc() {
    current = '';
    previous = '';
    displayCurrentResult.textContent = '0';
    displayPrevResult.textContent = '';
}


// Store current number, get operator and display it
function getOp(opStr) {
    opString = opStr;
    previous = current;
    displayPrevResult.textContent = previous;
    current = '';
}


// Get the number and display it
function getNum(num) {
    current += num;
    displayCurrentResult.textContent = current;
}



// Operating functions
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function subtract(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

function multiply(a, b) {
    return a * b;
}

function divide(a, b) {
    return a / b;
}

function operate(a, b) {
    return divide(b, a);
}

console.log(operate(22, 4));
```

```css
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.calcContainer {
    background: linear-gradient(276deg, #40a179, #77cea9);
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

button {
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0.1em;
    width: 40px;
    background: #a2ffaf;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
    background: #72e782;
}

.clr {
    background: #87e4bd;
}

.clr:hover {
    background: #53ad88;
}

.clear {
    margin: 0em 0.1em 0.5em 0.5em;
    padding: 0;
}

.output-clear-container {
    display: flex;
}

.output {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 40px;
    background: #c2fcca;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.par {
    margin-bottom: 0.3em;
}

.prev-result {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 0.3em;
    color:#40a179;
}

.current-result {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calcContainer">
        <div class="output-clear-container">
            <div class="output">
                <div class="prev-result"></div>
                <div class="current-result">0</div>
            </div>
            <button class="clear">AC</button>
        </div>
            <div class="par">
                <button class="number">7</button>
                <button class="number">8</button>
                <button class="number">9</button>
                <button class="operator clr">÷</button>
            </div>
            <div class="par">
                <button class="number">4</button>
                <button class="number">5</button>
                <button class="number">6</button>
                <button class="operator clr">x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="par">
                <button class="number">1</button>
                <button class="number">2</button>
                <button class="number">3</button>
                <button class="operator clr">-</button>
            </div>
            <div class="par">
                <button class="decimal clr">.</button>
                <button class="number">0</button>
                <button class="equal clr">=</button>
                <button class="operator clr">+</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: "I have to priorize multiplying and dividing over adding and subtracting, right?" that's not what the prompt asks you to do. "...each pair of numbers being evaluated at a time. For example, 12 + 7 - 5 * 3 = should yield 42". It'd be 4 following your mult/div first precedence. The logic is like on a calculator app or physical calculator if you hit `=` after every pair of numbers, so think of it like `(((12 + 7) - 5) * 3)`.

Comment: Yeah but the calculator actually does that, right? I mean, if I click 9 * 3 = 27 so it's evaluating a pair of numbers but when I concat another operation it won't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what it does currently, but it doesn't do that. I get 15 for the above equation--it works with `=` pressed after every op.

Comment: Ah, so I just need to figure it out how to do the same but after pressing an operator instead of =, right?

Comment: Pretty much, yes

Comment: Thank very much, I will think how to...